# Bootstrap modal enable background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my bootstrap modal be open but the page in the background still to be clickable.

There are a few solutions available on the web and stackoverflow (like [How do I make the background of a modal clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968336/how-do-i-make-the-background-of-a-modal-clickable)) which I tried but I could not get it to work. I'm working with Firefox and IE11.

**What I try to achieve**: Have a button at the side of the page that opens the modal, do stuff with model content, close modal either with click on button in header **or with click on button that opened the modal**.

There is a [working Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/CPG6z7GISf) where I try to adapt stuff from, without much success so far.

This is how far I've got:
**Modal**
(the html below gets generated in javascript, I just give you the output for better readability)

```
 <div id="bootstrapModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success " id="submitButton">Submit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" >Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var modal = $('#bootstrapModal');
$('.modal-backdrop', modal).css('display', 'none');
$('.modal-dialog',modal).css('pointer-events', 'none');
$('.modal-content',modal).css('pointer-events', 'all',);

$(modal).modal('show');
```

What I get is a modal with no backdrop but the possibility to interact with the background (background looks like it's active, but it's not). I get the same effect with

```
$(modal).modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
```

or when replacing `'static'` in `backdrop` with `false`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change/override the .modal class. When your window is open, if you inspect the background with your web inspector, you will see everything is contained in a div with the classes: **modal**, **fade** and **in**.
The "**modal**" class has the following css properties, which sets it to cover the whole screen, making your site unclickable.

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1050;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    outline: 0;
}
```

You would have to remove the **fixed** property or modify the **top**,**right**,**bottom** and **left** properties. However, if you removed the fixed property, you will not be able to use the z-index property, which gives your pop-up the overlay effect.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! My Toggle-Modal Button is on the very left of the page, so I needed to adjust the `left` property of the `modal` css. This fixed it for me: `$(modal).css('left','50px');`

Answer (score -1):

if I understand the problem you must put div behind the model and give it full width and height of page